# onload on html tag before the script tag

Tags: asynchronous, onload

I'm trying to get a function to run when some  element on the page is loaded

```html
   <img src="" onload="myfunction()">


   <footer>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
   </footer>
```

Now, the problem is that the page is trying to load the function before the js file is loaded
Do I have a solution other then loading the js file in the header??

Answer (score 1):

I'd have a tiny function that just waits until the JS file is loaded, and then call the function in the JS file. Example:

```html
<img src="" onload="stateCheck()">

<script>
let stateCheck = setInterval(() => {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') { // could use = 'interactive' too
    clearInterval(stateCheck);
    myfunction()
  }
}, 100);
</script>

<script src="main.js"></script>
```